# Create 2d context *without* canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am currently looking for a way to create a canvas 2d rendering context without actually having a canvas element on the page. I could dynamically create a canvas element and hide it, but then again I don't want to show the image directly to the user anytime, so there's no point of actually having a canvas element in the page. So I'm basicly looking for something that is similar to

```
var image = new Image( );
```

but only for canvas 2d rendering context (pseudo code)

```
var context = new 2dContext( );
```

Is there functionality like this? I wasn't able to find anything like it. Calling

```
var context = new CanvasRenderingContext2D( );
```

which is the name of the rendering context interface by HTML5 spec just gives me awkward errors in Firefox:

```
uncaught exception: [Exception... "Cannot convert WrappedNative to function" nsresult: "0x8057000d (NS_ERROR_XPC_CANT_CONVERT_WN_TO_FUN)" location: "JS frame :: http://localhost/ :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 25" data: no]
```

Comment: what's the point of the context then?  there may be a better way to accomplish what you want to do without using a context.  what made you decide to use a context and what is the need?

Comment: I am developing a browser based implementation of a board game that uses canvas to draw it's board. One important feature is that the board is actually bigger than your viewport to it, so you must be able to pan around. Panning requires very high refresh rates to look smooth and current ECMA Script + Canvas implementations simply do not provide that performance. So I was going to use a buffering approach which would draw the entire board to an invisble context, whenever something changes and clip parts of that context into the viewport canvas to (dramatically) increase refresh rates.

Comment: If you don't need anything *too* fancy/complex, you can generally get away with using/abusing HTML instead of looking for, say a SVG solution, or anything else other than `canvas` for that matter.

Comment: Does it help if you break the requirement into visual fragments and position them appropriately?

Comment: Well since one of the goals of that project was to better get into Javascript and especially Canvas I guess there's no point in moving away from canvas as a technology ;) Besides there's actally some more or less "fancy/complex" stuff going on, eg. drawing pathfinding results using interpolated bezier curves (-> Movement Arrows) which I couldn't do without dynamic drawing (canvas, SVG, whatever). I could of course use a hidden canvas to get the buffering context, and in fact it does work, pretty well aswell, but I just feel like "That's not nice and it shouldn't be neccessary".

Comment: "What's the point of the context then?" The point is that one may need a scratchpad context to do calculations before rendering the text onto the visible canvas. A prime example would be wordwrapping calculations.

Comment: **TL;DR:** `let context = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It is possible to use a canvas without displaying it on the page.  You could do the following:

```
// Create a canvas element
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 400;

// Get the drawing context
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Then you can do stuff, e.g.:
ctx.fillStyle = '#f00';
ctx.fillRect(20,10,80,50);
```

Once you've used the canvas, you can of course add it to the document

```
var element = document.getElementById('canvas_container');
element.appendChild(canvas);
```

Or you could make an image from it:

```
var new_image_url = canvas.toDataURL();
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = new_image_url;
```

Or you could access the canvas data as values with:

```
var image_data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
var rgba_byte_array = image_data.data;
rgba_byte_array[0];  // red value for first pixel (top left) in the canvas
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was aware of this method, but felt it's not exactly what I was looking for. Propably though this is my best bet.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work inside WebWorkers, which is my personal need. They don't have access to the DOM, but I want to do some drawing operations on a background thread.

Answer (score 4):

Interestingly enough, if you create a canvas object and store its context in a variable, that variable has its own pointer to the canvas object. Since you can't use getContext("2d") without a canvas, you might as well only have one canvas pointer. If you're like me and hate having a two references to the same object, you could do this:

Original:

```
var canvas=document.createElement("canvas");
var context=canvas.getContext("2d");

alert(Boolean(context.canvas==canvas));// true.
```

What I'm talking about:

```
var context=document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");

alert(context.canvas);// The canvas object.
```

Now you can do all of your important canvas stuff through the context variable. After all, context is accessed more often than the canvas variable. When you do need it just reference it through the context:

```
context.canvas.width=320;
context.canvas.height=320;
document.body.appendChild(context.canvas);
```

And if you don't want to bother with the canvas just leave the variable alone, it's not like you wanted to use it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

How about: OffscreenCanvas()?

And the answer is probably no, since this is only supported in Firefox 44.0+  currently.

```
var offscreen = new OffscreenCanvas(256, 256);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-offscreencanvas-interface

(Added for reference here, as this may well be new to the spec since this question was asked more than 6 years ago!  And hopefully will be more widely adopted)