# Is it okay to hold a reference to a canvas 2d context?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Is it okay to hold a long-lasting reference to a canvas context (one obtained by `getContext('2d')`)? In particular, might there be issues if the canvas element is resized? If there are issues, would it improve matters to use a context obtained from a separate canvas node (as described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892010/create-2d-context-without-canvas)) instead of one derived from the DOM?

The reason for the question is, I need to do a lot of text metric calculations behind the scenes and I thought that maintaining a reference to a context would be a good way to do this.

Comment: doesnt matter since the context has a reference to the canvas...

Comment: @camus - I'm not sure what that has to do with it. The context also has references to other stuff; it's that other stuff (perhaps off-screen bitmaps or system resources?) that I'm concerned about.

Comment: Have tried both situations and benchmarking the result?

Comment: @Dave - I'm not asking about performance, but about how safe a practice it is, particularly across browsers (including mobile browsers). I haven't found problems on a couple of browsers (Chrome, FF) in the little testing I've done, but that doesn't mean a whole lot, since I don't know what problems to test for. I'm hoping that someone with knowledge of JS engine internals can weigh in.

Comment: Are you worried about security problems or bug related problems ? But as @camus said im not sure its going to make a difference.

Comment: @Dave - I'm worried about bugs. I'm relatively inexperienced with JS, so I'm not sure the question even makes a lot of sense. My concern is based on experience with certain other platforms where holding a long-lasting reference to some types of graphics objects prevents critical system resources from being freed when they need to be (e.g., when the graphics layer changes size). Of course, in JS there may be different kinds of things that could go wrong, or maybe there's nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never had any problems with storing a reference to a context. Resizing canvas doesn't affect it.

Spec doesn't seem to mention anything about new context in [resizing section](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#concept-canvas-set-bitmap-dimensions).

However, I would take a closer look at [setContext section](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-canvas-setcontext), just in case.

Comment: Thanks. This seems reassuring. The spec talks about directly creating a context using `new CanvasRenderingContext2D([width,height])`. I thought this might be a cleaner way to obtain a context. However, Chrome and FF throw "TypeError: Illegal constructor" when I try to invoke it in the console and IE 9 complains "Object doesn't support this action". Can this feature actually be used?

Comment: I doubt it. Never seen this used or mentioned anywhere. Even though CanvasRenderingContext2D is exposed in WebKit, I see that it's not even inheriting from Function (`CanvasRenderingContext2D instanceof Function` is `false` and so there's no `call` or `apply`). However spec seems to suggest that `CanvasRenderingContext2D` could be used as a constructor, in which case it _"returns an unbound CanvasRenderingContext2D object with an implied bitmap"_ — http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#2d-context-creation-algorithm